# Очистка памяти в векторе

Tags: c++, vector

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.assign(50,100);
v.assign(30,100);
```

Требуется ли очищать память от `v[30], v[31], ..., v[49]` ?

Comment: Если Вы ничего не выделяли, то и очищать ничего не нужно.

Comment: @ixSci более того, иногда не нужно очищать даже если выделял.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не требуется - вектор достаточно сообразителен, чтобы почиститься.